# Why does CLion C++ suggestions require multiple presses of Ctrl+Space, and sometimes fail to auto-import?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using CLion 2022.3.3. When I open a new project and type `std::vec`, I'm expecting the first suggestion to be `std::vector`, and I can press TAB and will automatically add `#include <vector>` at the top of the page.

Instead what happens is I do *not* see `std::vector`. I have to press ctrl+space, which *still* doesn't give suggestions, but gives a popup saying "no suggestions, press Ctrl+space for not imported members". So I press Ctrl+space a *second* time and *finally* I get the `std::vector` suggestion, and TAB gives the auto-import, as expected.

Why do I need to press ctrl+space *twice* just for this? Is there a setting I'm missing here? I have all default settings.

Worse, when I tried the same thing with `std::fi`, I again needed to ctrl+space twice, but this time when TABing on `std::find`, there was *no* auto-import.

What's happening here? Why is the CLion C++ experience seemingly so bad? In comparison, in Idea the Java experience is so pleasant; the suggestions immediately appear, and imports just work. Same with CLion for the Rust plugin, and Goland for Go. What's going on? Does this happen for anyone else?

I suspect it's some sort of clangd issue, and [this thread from FreeBSD forums](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=263122) says something similar.

I've also noticed [similar issues from CLion with CUDA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7440124589458-CLion-code-completion-for-CUDA-is-missing-many-options)